# Loop horizontal in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make a horizontal loop, for a stored procedure. Right now I use updates to fill the columns horizontally. I find it inefficient and time consuming when I have to change a condition for example, then I have to change it at 28 places. The user has requested the data horizontally, hence why I'll try change the SP to loop it. Although I have never done this before and not sure if it's even possible in SQL?

```
Insert into #ExcelPrint (Col01,Col02)
Select 'Åtg 8:00', Sum(Convert(int,t.Amount)) from
Maintenance.dbo.Table t
where Time = '8:00'
and DATEPART(yy,Datum)= DATEPART(YY,Dateadd(DD,0,GETDATE()))
and DATEPART(MM,Datum)= DATEPART(MM,Dateadd(DD,0,GETDATE()))
and DATEPART(DD,Datum)= DATEPART(DD,Dateadd(DD,0,GETDATE()))

Update #ExcelPrint
Set Col03 = (Select Sum(Convert(int,ha.Amount)) from 
Maintenance.dbo.table t
where Time = '8:00'
and DATEPART(yy,Datum)= DATEPART(YY,Dateadd(DD,-1,GETDATE()))
and DATEPART(MM,Datum)= DATEPART(MM,Dateadd(DD,-1,GETDATE()))
and DATEPART(DD,Datum)= DATEPART(DD,Dateadd(DD,-1,GETDATE())))
where row = (Select COUNT(*) from #ExcelPrint)
```

The Update continues untill dd,-6 so a week back. I want to make this a loop horinzontally, it will definetly make things better for the future in my SP.

Comment: Are you just looking to take a normalised data set (one row per date and time) and `PIVOT` it (one row per date, 24 * n columns, with n columns per hour)?  *(Please also note, although this may be a good output to a human user, and so perfectly valid in a presentation layer, I doubt it will make any coding better in the future.  De-normalised data is an anti-pattern in SQL, it's us humans that prefer viewing it, but for SQL statements you just don't want it.)*   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: Yes a normalised data set. The data is already placed in a table that I get data from, all I need to is loop it horizontally. It uses less computing power and system memory to loop it than to use updates the way I do now. I have about 20 more of the code I placed above, 2 for each day in a week, and 2 datatypes... about 28 updates feels to much

Comment: Look into using `PIVOT` or search SO for manual pivots using `SUM(CASE WHEN)` with `GROUP BY`.